# Alfresco: send workflow form data to custom datalist

Tags: workflow, alfresco, datalist

I have an advanced workflow setup that starts with a form. My goal is to have the form's data sent to my custom datalist, but I have no idea how to go about this, and other questions on this site didn't help.

Specific questions:

- **Is this possible?**
- If so, what's the best way to go about this (like running a script)?
- Are there existing resources online that I haven't located on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Regarding how you can do this,You can do this by defining custom action and calling it from alfresco javascript,which you will write in workflow.

How you can define custom action ,that you can find from below link.
https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions

In case of how you can call custom action from workflow below link will help you.
http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html#step-2-implement-web-scripts-and-actions

Regarding what you will be coding in Java class file below link will help you.
https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/how-create-datalist-java-api-alfresco-4.

In alfresco javascript you can call custom action with below code.

```
var createDataListItem=actions.create("your bean name");
createDataListItem.execute("Here node goes");//May be name of your datalist or something like that
```

Comment: Would it be possible to call the Javascript in this post http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/18/using-the-javascript-console-creating-and-populating-datalists/ from the workflow instead of a custom action? Or is this the wrong method for going about this? I'm just having trouble working on implementing the custom action executer.

Comment: I did not get your question.

Comment: Instead of creating a new class extending ActionExecuterAbstractBase, could I just use the Javascript in that link above?